# How can I convert string virtual key code to virtual key code?

Tags: key

I have created xml file in which I have added all keys as nodes and its respective virtual key codes as a value. I am fetching those values and storing it in string format.
I need output as:
When I press key 0 its corresponding value is 0x30
But my PressKey function uses Keybd_event which takes virtual key code as an argument.

```
public bool Presskey(byte buttonVirtualKey)
{
   keybd_event(buttonVirtualKey, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I need to convert the string formatted virtual key code("0x30") to byte value(0x30).

Any type of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot convert string of form "0x30" to bytes because the Convert class expects a string of the form "30" to be able to convert. Also the convert class uses decimal base and not hexa-decimal. So you first have to convert "30" to decimal value and then use the decimal value in Convert.ToBytes(int) function,i.e,

int decValue = int.Parse("30", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

Convert.ToByte(decValue);